# Only show one div in webview

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I have been trying to implement this but I could not get it work. Anyway here is the deal:

In the main page of a website, I only want a specific div to be shown in a webview. Hide all other elements. But keep the styling and scripts of that page of course.(This means no Jsoup)

I tried doing it by using javascript in webview and here is what I tried:

```
    webview = (WebView) this.findViewById(R.id.webView);
    final WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();

    settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    settings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);

    WebViewClient myClient = new WebViewClient(){

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
            Log.e("LogTxt","Test");
            view.loadUrl("javascript:var con = document.getElementsByClassName('page-content'); " +"con[0].style.display = 'none'; ");
        }
    };

    String cookieString = ".ASPXAUTH="+ getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
    headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("Cookie", cookieString);
    headers.put("Accept","mobile");

    webview.setWebViewClient(myClient);
    webview.loadUrl("http://www.myurl.com",headers);
```

Looks like this:

[image]

So how can I do this? What are other alternative ways? Thanks!

Comment: Give a try with `"javascript:document.getElementById(\"YourDivId\").setAttribute(\"style\",\"display:none;\");"`

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the element I want to hide actually have no id, but it has a class name. <div class = "page">

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"javascript:(function() {document.getElementsByTagName('YourDivTag')[0].remove();})()"
```